# Why won't my Pygame sprite jump code work?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I am trying to make my Pygame sprite jump so I followed a tutorial and this is what it gave me. But it doesn't work for some reason. What's wrong with it

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if isjump == False:
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        if isjump:
            F =(1 / 2)*m*(v**2)
            player.rect.y -= F
            v = v-1
        if v<0:
            m =-1
        if v ==-6:
                isjump = False
                v = 5
                m = 1
```

Comment: without full code which we could run I can only suggest to use `print()` to see values in variable and which part of code is executed.

Comment: what means `doesn't work` ? do you get error message? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: if you run code in `if isjump == False:` then for sure `isjump` is `False` and checking `if isjump` will be always `False`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set somewher `isjump = True`. Additionally the `if isjump == False:` needs an `else` case:

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if isjump == False:
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        isjump = true    
        v = 5
else:
    m = 1 if v >= 0 else -1
    F = m * (v**2)
    player.rect.y -= F
    
    v -= 1
    if v == -6:
        isjump = False
```